# Read RF from Remote trouble

Tags: gpio, arduino, radio

I have myself a Raspberry pi and Arduino which I've equipped with a 433mhz transmitter (to the arduino) and a 433mhz receiver to the Pi.

I can read the output fine from the transmitter in Pi console so I know that my wiring and set-up is correct, however I'm having trouble detecting anything at all from my RF remote control which is used for RF power sockets.

My remote is 433.92mhz and I know that is works, as I always use it.

I'm just not picking up anything at all, I tried looking for different pulse rates but I was literally just guessing numbers so I don't think I was ever going to get anywhere with that.

What would be the best way of debugging this without having to buy additional modules or equipment ? (I've already spent a fair bit on this)

Comment: It is hard to tell as the remote might have different baud rate, or different encoding. The transmitter and receiver module usually use ASK modulation,  Maybe even the modulation is not match.

Comment: Yeah the remotes come with little to no documentation so It's really hard to troubleshoot, I might even send them back and get the energenie ones

Comment: What has the Arduino got to do with the question?  I don't understand what is meant to be transmitting and what is meant to be receiving.

Comment: Well the Arduino transmits a code using 433mhz and the Pi receives the code using 433mhz. 
The idea is to capture 433mhz codes from my RF remote so I can then get rid of the remote all together and just use my computer to control things

Comment: That is still not clear.  Are you trying to receive a remote control signal transmitted from a 433MHz fob with a 433MHz receiver connected to a Pi GPIO?  What is the point of the Arduino in this scenario?

Comment: I think the point of mentioning the Arduino is just to demonstrate that the receiver on the pi is hooked up correctly and works in that context.

Comment: That's correct @joan , and like goldilocks said, I'm just demonstrating that it works with the Arduino

Comment: Okay.  In that case could you say what software you are using at the Pi end to read the RF remote radio signal and more importantly is it exactly the same software you are using to receive the Arduino radio signal.

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/ninjablocks/433Utils which is an adaptation of rcswitch. And yes I'm using the same library on the Arduino.

Answer (score 1):

To debug the radio signal being received at the Pi you could try my [piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html) utility.  It will work locally on a Pi2/Pi3 but if possible it's best to run the display on a more powerful Linux PC.  It will display the signals arriving at a Pi GPIO.

A quicker test would be to compile and run one of my fob programs.

I suggest you try [_433D](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pdif2__433D) as that is the most recent.  That will attempt to decode a fob which uses Manchester Encoded signals which I believe to be the commonest protocol in use.

Comment: Ah yes I came across this while looking for solutions earlier, I couldn't get it to work then realised that I hadn't installed pigpiod :p
This is the set I bought with the remote https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B014614ODW/ 
Will that work with your utility?

Comment: @user49485 I don't know.  All I have to test with is one of those 4 button keyfobs which generate one of 16 codes depending on which combination of buttons are pressed.  You'll have to try and see.